# How to override DatePicker of cart price rule and add time within it in, Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, catalog-price-rules

I want to save it in date field no another field and not a new item

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0icp0.jpg

Example of the outcome I am looking for

Comment: hi, here am adding date with time at cart price rules form, i want to add time  how to add it, can you help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="rule_information" sortOrder="10">
        <field name="from_date" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="to_date" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: **@Sohel Rana** Thank you so much for replaying , that is working , thank you

Comment: but Magento 2 not validating that, it showing error that **Enter Valid Date**, i changed database column as DATETIME, still its not submitting